# SQLAlchemy sum of Decimals always zero?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following table models using flask and sqlalchemy:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import func

app = Flask(__name__)
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = "..."
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE"] = 299
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

class Round(db.Model):
   __tablename__ = "rounds"
  round_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  outcome = db.Column(db.Integer)

class Play(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "plays"
   play_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
   round_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('rounds.round_id'))
   user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.user_id'))
   guess = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I am trying to calculate a uniqueness score for each of the users based on how many other users have also scored correctly in the same round. To do this, I first calculate the uniqueness for each of the rounds of play like this:

```
>>> scored_plays = Play.query.join(Round).join(User).filter(Round.outcome == Play.guess)
>>> round_uniqueness = scored_plays.with_entities(Play.play_id, (1.0 / func.count(User.user_id)).label("coeff")).group_by(Play.round_id)
```

So far this works ok, producing an output like:

```
>>> round_uniqueness.all()
[(1, 0.16667), (3, 0.33333), ...]
```

I try to join this back to `scored_plays` to connect the `user_id` and the `coeff` like this:

```
>>> users_with_coeff = scored_plays.join(round_uniqueness.subquery()).with_entities(Play.user_id, "coeff")
>>> users_with_coeff.all()
[(123, Decimal('0.16667'), (456, Decimal('0.16667'), ...]
```

This still looks correct as the `len()` of this output corresponds to the `len()` of `scored_plays`. But, when I try to group this on `user_id` and sum the `coeff` I keep getting zeros. I tested with `count` instead, and the aggregation works fine, but `sum` or `avg` just return zeros, like this:

```
>>> user_coeff_sum = scored_plays.join(round_uniqueness.subquery()).with_entities(Play.user_id, func.sum("coeff")).group_by(Play.user_id)
>>> user_coeff_sum.all()
[(123, 0.0), (456, 0.0), ...]
```

I suspect the reason behind this lies in the `Decimal` object, but have no idea how to elegantly handle it in this context to get the sum to work.

Thanks!